# Using wait() inside a synchronized block

Tags: java, android, concurrency, android-service, java-threads

I stumbled upon a piece of code in an Android Service class that has a synchronized block with a wait statement. 
The code is as follows:

```
    public class MyService extends IntentService{

     protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){
     synchronized(this){
        try{
           wait(10000);         
           }catch(InterruptedException e){
           e.printStackTrack();
         }
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("Message");
        showMessage(message);
       }
      }
    }
```

Does the above code means that any number of threads can enter the `synchronized` block? I know that `sleep` puts the `Thread` in a Blocked state. Is this the same with a `Thread` calling `wait()`?
Basically when I pass a text to the `Service`, I want the `Service` to wait for 10 seconds then display the message in the `LogCat`.
I have never used `wait()` anytime so could anybody explain to me what the above code is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement "any number of threads can enter the `synchronized` block" is false.

Theoretically, if one thread is inside the `synchronized` block, this prevents other threads from entering. Which is not possible in the case of `IntentService` because `IntentService` uses a single worker thread to handle the workload.

Calling `wait()` is a thread synchronization method, not a delay method. This is different from calling `sleep()` which just blocks the thread for a specific amount of time.  When you call `wait()` this blocks the thread until another thread calls `notify()`, which is used to coordinate activities among multiple threads. `wait(10000)` blocks the thread until either `notify()` is called from another thread OR until the timeout expires (in this case 10 seconds). So this looks like there should be another thread somewhere which is calling `notify()` on the `IntentService` object to wake it up.

There is an additional complexity here associated with the use of `notify()` and `wait()`. In order to call either of these methods, a lock on the object's monitor must first be obtained (by the use of `synchronized`). This means that calls to `wait()` and `notify()` must be within `synchronized` blocks or within `synchronized` methods that are `synchronized` on the object.

The thread that calls `wait()` actually releases the lock on the object. This means that the thread is blocked inside a `synchronized` block/method but it **does not have a lock on the object while waiting**. Once `notify()` is called (or the timeout has expired), the thread will regain the lock on the object and continue executing.

For more information about using `notify()` and `wait()` in Java, search for these terms and read about it.

---

This code is pretty convoluted if all it is supposed to do is delay 10 seconds and then write a something to logcat. You could just call `sleep()` instead of `wait()` which would not require the `synchronized` statement. However, as another poster noted, if this `Service` is called very often, this will create a backlog as each and every call to `onHandleIntent()` will be delayed by 10 seconds and since there is only 1 worker thread, all calls are serialized. Example: a call to `startService()` is made at 10:00:00, the entry in the logcat will appear at 10:00:10. If another call to `startService()` is made at 10:00:01, that entry will not appear in the logcat until 10:00:20, because the second call to `onHandleIntent()` will not happen until 10:00:10.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your question deals with multithreading, which is a pretty complicated topic. I recommend starting out with a [tutorial like this one](https://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/) to get those answers.

The above code will serve to delay log entries by 10 seconds. However, `IntentService` only has 1 worker thread, so successive requests will get backlogged if they occur more often than once every 10 seconds.

Because only 1 worker thread is involved, using synchronization is really the wrong answer. Why not ditch the IntentService, and just do all this on the UI thread, using a `CountDownTimer`?

```
final String msg = intent.getStringExtra("Message");

new CountDownTimer(10000, 10000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

    @Override
    public void onFinish()  {
        showMessage(msg);
    }
}.start();
```

That way, you can create the *appearance* of parallel execution, without the complexity of multithreading, by taking advantage of Android's [built-in message queueing system](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper).